# Проблема в задаче

Tags: c++, алгоритм

*Условие задачи:*

> Во время нового года особым спросом пользуются разноцветные елочные
>   шарики. В 2018 году алхимия дошла аж до того, что для создания
>   необходимого елочного шарика достаточно взять пару-тройку магических
>   кристаллов разных цветов и немного пошаманить.
>
> Грише требуется получить несколько шариков желтого, зеленого и синего
>   цветов. Достоверно известно, что для получения одного желтого шарика
>   требуются два магических кристалла желтого цвета, зеленого — один
>   желтый и один синий, а для синего — три кристалла синего цвета.
>
> На настоящий момент Гриша располагает A кристаллами желтого цвета и B
>   кристаллами синего цвета. Определите, сколько кристаллов ему требуется
>   дополнительно приобрести, чтобы суметь создать необходимое число
>   шариков. Входные данные
>
> В первой строке заданы числа A и B (0 ≤ A, B ≤ 10^9) — количество
>   имеющихся у Гриши желтых и синих кристаллов.
>
> Во второй строке следуют три числа x, y, z (0 ≤ x, y, z ≤ 10^9) —
>   необходимое число елочных шариков желтого, зеленого и синего цветов.
>   Выходные данные
>
> Выведите одно число — минимальное количество дополнительных
>   кристаллов, которые придется приобрести Грише.

Вроде бы просто, да? Так и есть. Только одна проблема: в третьем примере вывода у меня почему-то выскакивает отрицательное значение, хоть и равное по модулю необходимому. В чем проблема? Скрин и код прилагается.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int zhel, zel, sin, zhelt, siniy, nuzhnzhel, nuzhnsin, all;
    cin >> zhelt >> siniy >> zhel >> zel >> sin;
    nuzhnzhel = zhel * 2 + zel - zhelt;
    nuzhnsin = sin * 3 + zel - siniy;
    all = nuzhnzhel + nuzhnsin;
    cout << all;
}
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Ну так а ситуацию, когда изначально у вас уже есть больше кристаллов, чем необходимо, вы никак не обрабатываете.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не вписываются значения в диапазон `int`...
Возьмите, например, `long long`.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо! Тупанул)